# Blender 2.8 PNG image is not transparent even with alpha blend and alpha nodes

Tags: image, transparency

I have a transparent image that I created as a plane and I can't seem to get it to be transparent. I've saved the PNG with the color and alpha data and it still not transparent even with the nodes connected.
I am using Blender 2.81 please help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your *Color Space* is also set to *sRGB OETF*, [which was never designed for rendering](https://sobotka.github.io/filmic-blender/#why). Can you set it to sRGB at all?

Comment: @vklidu A little OT, but isn't that Brno main railway station in your image?

Comment: Could this be something with Windows? When I save the image and view it in Windows it doesn't show it to be transparent. Is there a way I can share this png with you guys?

Comment: A bit late now you have solved the issue, but you edit the question and use the image button to upload the image to imgur.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the [Blend Mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#blend-mode) in the material settings and have to be in Rendered View.

[image: blend mode]

Any of *Alpha Clip*, *Alpha Hashed* or *Alpha Blend* would work for a single image, but for a pixel perfect preview in EEVEE, *Alpha Blend* is required.

> **Alpha Blending**
>   Use alpha blending to overlay the surface color on top of the previous color.

Comment: but he is using Alpha Blend type ...

Comment: You're right. Perhaps they are not in rendered view, or the image has no alpha.

Comment: Yes I have tried all those options, I still get no transparency.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

When I was saving the transparent image I didn't have the output file include the alpha data, so when I enabled RGBA the image was then transparent.

[image]

Comment: Tip: Don't use PNG. It's a broken cancerous format.

Comment: PS sometimes it will no apear if you switch from jpeg to png for example, the enumerator will not update correctly

Answer (score -2):

You need to mix with a transparent shader and use image alpha as the mix factor.

Comment: I've tried this and it has the same issue.