# How to add an image with transparent background to a textured wall?

Tags: texturing, image, transparency

I want to upload an image with transparent background to a textured wall. How do I do this?

My image is a hieroglyphic inscription, which has a transparent background edited in Adobe Photoshop.

The wall is a mesh that has a Sandstone Texture added onto it.

I want to add my image on top of this wall, without taking away the wall's texture.

Pretty much like a graffiti.

The issue I have is this: when I add my image to Blender, the background isn't transparent, as it should be.

How should I proceed?

Comment: That's the old Blender. Is there a guide for the new Blender? When I add an image with transparent background, it doesn't show as transparent at all.

Comment: Still the same, You're welcome. Related for Eevee (if that's your issue), https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160362/blender-2-8-png-image-is-not-transparent-even-with-alpha-blend-and-alpha-nodes and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193080/how-can-i-make-an-image-plane-have-transparency-in-eevee-with-nodes

Comment: The link that @brockmann gave you holds all the information you need. Especially the explanation of alpha channels and mixing materials with a Transparent BSDF shader does what you want. There's also a section describing it for the Principled BSDF shader. It still works in recent versions of Blender.

Comment: It works now, the reason it didnt work is because the image i was using didn't really have a transparent background. Thanks a lot :)